# Create principal from JWT and set it to SecurityContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

In one system, I generated the JWT token as follows:

```
List securityGroups = Arrays.asList("group1");
Map<String, Object> claims = Map.of("username", "user1", "securityGroups", securityGroups);
String token = Jwts.builder()
    .setClaims(claims).setSubject("user1").setAudience("web")
    .setIssuedAt(<date now>).setExpiration(<some expiration>)
    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "mysecret").compact();
```

In another application, I want to decrypt this token and set in the SecurityContext.  First, I have security config as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disabled().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/principal").permitAll()
            .anyRequests().authenticated();
    }
}
```

With this, when user requests for an endpoint, say `/books`, the browser will receive 403 error.

Then I implement the `/principal` to use this token as an authenticated user in spring.

```
@RequestMapping("/principal")
public class PrincipalController {
    @PostMapping
    public void setPrincipal(@RequestBody String token) {
        // i'm able to decrypt the token here
        // use token to create principal
        Authentication authentication = ....
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(...)
    }
}
```

I'm thinking once I set this in SecurityContext, for succeeding request where I attach the token in the Authorization header, I won't be getting anymore 403 or 401 error since user is authenticated and Spring knows that the token corresponds to the principal in the context.  But this part I am not sure how to do it.  Please advise.

Comment: https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1?source=rss-------1

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with **spring-security built-it JWT support** for a server secured with JWT.

First, for a spring-boot application you'll need a dependency:
*for Gradle:*

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:2.7.4'
```

*for Maven:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in any configuration class create beans of `JwtDecoder` type and a converter to convert some JWT claim to a collection of `GrantedAuthority`.

In your case it can be done like this:

```java
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec("mysecret".getBytes(), JwsAlgorithms.HS512);
    final NimbusJwtDecoder decoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(key).build();
    return decoder;
}

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("securityGroups");
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("");

    final JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

Then just let your application know that you want to use this support by additional security filter chain configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConf {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disabled().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/principal").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Server -> oauth2Server.jwt());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Note that I don't use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` because it's **deprecated** now.

Above configuration will create a filter which will try to authorize users before reaching your controller endpoints and will throw 401 if there's no JWT or it's expired or invalid for other reasons.

So you won't need a separate endpoint like `"/principal"` for "login" with a token, because Spring will create an `Authentication` object in a `SecurityContextHolder` for every request.

Moreover, this configuration will let you authorize users depending on their "securityGroups", so if you decide to configure some role-based or authority-based access to some endpoints Spring will check it for you and return 403 if authorities are insufficient.

Comment: also Spring lets you configure some additional JWT checks, e.g. if you want to check if the *issuer* of JWT is correct

Comment: It didn’t work.  Instead of returning `http`, I return `http.build()`.  Even with keeping the /principal permitall still I get 401. Removing it also got 401.

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev sorry about `http.build()`, my mistake - i made an edit to the post. did you try to debug? what is the reason of 401?